Created chrome extension for native messaging not getting response back to browser
Created chrome extension for native messaging added an entry in registry as well.
Hosted test.html in IIS and open the url can able to see the button “Send/Receive NativeMessaege” click on this will launch the windows app(c#) and it will show the message “Hello world :)”  received from content script, C# sending back the message but not able to receive in  content script will get the below error.
Error Unchecked runtime. lastError: The message port closed before a response was received, In browser and below error in extension.
Note : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/api-samples/nativeMessaging tried this it will work with  in extensions. If I open main.html in browser will get the below error.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connectNative')
at HTMLButtonElement.connect (main.js:43:25)


Sample Code 

Test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> native messsaging</title> 
</head>
<body>
<button id="sendreceiveButton"  >Send/Receive NativeMessaege</button>
</body>
</html>

ContentSript.js
var button = document.getElementById("sendreceiveButton");
button.addEventListener("click",async function ()
{   const result= await window.chrome.runtime.sendMessage( {
          type: 'info',
            value: 'Hello world :)'
        }, (response) => 

 {     

 if (response) {          console.log(response);

  }    });

   console.log(result);
});

Host-Manifest.json
{
    "name": "test.native",
    "description": "Something something",
    "path": "<<Path>>\\WindowsFormsApp1.exe",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
        "chrome-extension://<<extensionID>>/"
    ]   
}


Background.js
let port = null;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (request, sender, sendResponse)=>{
 
 
      port =  chrome.runtime.connectNative("test.native");
     
         port.postMessage(request.value);
        
         port.onMessage.addListener((response)=>{
              sendResponse(response);
         });
             
         port.onDisconnect.addListener(()=>{
             if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
             {
                 
                  sendResponse({response});
             }
         });
        
    
 
});




Manifest.json
{
    "name": "NativeMessaging API ",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "A basic example using c#",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // must specify the nativeMessaging otherwise it wont work //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    "permissions": [
        "tabs","nativeMessaging" 
    ],
    "browser_action": {},
    "manifest_version": 2
}


C# 

   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string message = ReadMessage();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                SendResponse("Saved successfully");
        }

        
        string ReadMessage()
        {
            try
            {


                byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[4];
                Console.OpenStandardInput().Read(lengthBytes, 0, 4);
                int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes, 0);
                byte[] messageBytes = new byte[length];
                Console.OpenStandardInput().Read(messageBytes, 0, length);

                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes);
                textBox1.Text += message;

                return message;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textBox1.Text += ex.Message;

            }

            return null;
        }
        void SendResponse(object responseObject)
        {
            string responseJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseObject);
            Console.OpenStandardOutput().Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(responseJson.Length), 0, 4);
            Console.OpenStandardOutput().Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseJson), 0, responseJson.Length);
            Console.OpenStandardOutput().Flush();
        }

        private static async Task WriteToExtension(string sMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                var strmToExt = Console.OpenStandardOutput();

                if (null == strmToExt) return;
                byte[] arrPayload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sMessage);
                byte[] arrSize = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt32)arrPayload.Length);
                await strmToExt.WriteAsync(arrSize, 0, 4);
                if (null == strmToExt) return;
                await strmToExt.WriteAsync(arrPayload, 0, arrPayload.Length);
                if (null == strmToExt) return;
                await strmToExt.FlushAsync();
                if (null == strmToExt) return;
            }
            catch (Exception eX)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to send message\n" + eX.Message, "WriteToExtension Failed");
            }
        }

       
    }


Add return true at the end of onMessage listener.
